# Efficient way to count the greater than operation for each value itself

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a numpy vector containing real values.
For each value in this vector i want to count the number of values greater than value itself.

For example:

```
input: array([1.,2.,3.,1.,1.,0.,10.]) # numpy array
output: array([3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 6, 0])
```

My first idea was:

```
# pandas
df[column].apply(lambda x: (df[column] > x).sum())

# numpy equivalent 
[(arr>x).sum() for x in arr]
```

But it's very slow. Is there efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way to do this is by using Python's `bisect` module:

```
import bisect
array = [1.,2.,3.,1.,1.,0.,10.]
n = len(array)
sorted_array = sorted(array)
print [n - bisect.bisect(sorted_array, val) for val in array]
```

This creates a sorted copy of the array, and then uses binary search into the sorted array to determine, for each of the original elements, how many values are greater.

The algorithm has `O(n logn)` time complexity compared to the original code's `O(n^2)`. For comparison, I tested it on an input array of 100K elements and it was 200x faster.

P.S. The whole thing can be rewritten as a NumPy one-liner:

```
output = array.size - np.searchsorted(np.sort(array), array, side='right')
```

On my 100K-element test array, it is 1300x faster than the original.

Comment: i've found a numpy analogue for this `np.searchsorted(sorted_array, val,side='right')`. Pretty clever solution!

Comment: @f311a: Please see the updated answer on how to write the whole thing as a NumPy one-liner.

Comment: *claps* Very nice.